# Javascript function not returning from within a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript function as:

```
function nodeExists(text, ancestor, tree, generationCount) {

tree.findByText(text).each(function (index, element) {

    var gen = generationCount;
    var currNode = element;
    while (gen !== 1) { // 1: node itself

        currNode = tree.parent(currNode);
        gen--;
    }

    if (tree.text(currNode) === ancestor)
        return currNode; // Even if condition is met, control continues looping       
})       

return null;
//return ($.inArray(ancestor, gArr) !== -1) ? true : false;
}
```

While debugging function not exiting from a loop even if `tree.text(currNode) === ancestor` is truthy. Is Jquery .each causing it. Please help me.

Comment: First question, what's being passed for generationCount?  I would also suggest that you don't do `while (gen !== 1)` but instead, `while (gen > 1)`, just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Only returning `false` will stop the iteration with `each`, use `break` or `return false` so `element == currNode`

Comment: Down-vote is OK for immature question.

Comment: @Scott generationCount is integer > 1. While while(gen > 1) works good, what is its benefit over while(gen !== 1), some kind of cuteness or performance reasons?

Comment: @Binbsr: The advantage is that if this is somehow called with a bad value of generationCount, such as 0 or -73, or "abc", the code won't get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @Scott thanks for the explanation. I will keep that in mind. In my case, generationCount will never be villain for me since (1<generationCount<1000).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation:

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
>   callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

You aren't returning false so the loop will continue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try an alert instead of a return ? Perhaps your ancestor is not "===" but just "==" to your tree.text(currNode) ?

Comment: I don't need alerts, since i am debugging it line by line :). And === is deliberate, since it is fast (don't need type conversions) than ==. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to return 'false'. Otherwise, it will go to next iteration.

Comment: Thanks, i already accepted the answer for nice advice, i can't vote you up (Sorry to my reputation score).